# Apply/remove bitmask depending on condition

Tags: c, bitmask

I would like to simplify the following expression (`block` is an integer, either `0` or `1`):

```
if (block)
    opts = opts & ~O_NONBLOCK;
else
    opts = opts | O_NONBLOCK;
```

This is what I've come up with:

```
opts = block ? opts & ~O_NONBLOCK : opts | O_NONBLOCK;
```

I'm sure, however, that there's a much clever way to do that.

Comment: Debugging is twice as hard as writing it in the first place. If you write it as cleverly as you possibly can.. :-))

Comment: You're right! I don't think I'll be using the "most clever" solution, but I'm just curious actually.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im It either clears or sets the `O_NONBLOCK` bits, depending on whether `block` is set or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
opts = (opts & ~O_NONBLOCK) | (!block * O_NONBLOCK);
```

I do prefer the explicitness of your first option over this somewhat cryptic solution, though.

Comment: The factor should be `(1-block)`, not `block` (which illustrates the crypticness ;).

Comment: Ta. Fixed it to use `!block` instead.

Comment: I guess I was looking for something like that. Really cryptic, that's for sure!

Comment: Works too. Might introduce a branch, though. (I don't know the instruction set. If there's a dedicated instruction for it, that would probably be faster than `1-block`.)

Comment: I accepted your solution since it seems to be the most compact one. However, I'm going to keep using the if/else variant with compound-assignments, I guess. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @DanielFischer Interesting question! For x86-64, `gcc -O2` generates `cmpl    $1, 8(%ebp)  sbbl    %edx, %edx`, which appears to be a branchless sequence to get `-1` into `%edx` when `8(%ebp)` is nonzero. Having `-1` in `%edx`, the multiplication from this answer is translated as a less costly bitwise and. http://www.fermi.mn.it/linux/quarta/x86/sbb.htm

Comment: @PascalCuoq My gcc (4.6.2, on x86_64 Linux) produces a multiplication either way. I get `cmpl; sbbl; andl` from clang with `!block` if `block` is an `int`. With `block` a `bool`, gcc still produces an `imull`, but clang does an `xorl $-2; incl; andl` (clever ;) for both variants. Don't know what would be faster, though.

Answer (score 2):

Your first example is about as simple as it could possibly be, and certainly is better at explaining what's going on.

If for some reason you're desperate to type fewer characters, you *could* use assignment operators, I suppose:

```
if (block)
    opts &= ~O_NONBLOCK;
else
    opts |= O_NONBLOCK;
```

I certainly wouldn't go down the ternary operator route if you can avoid it.

Comment: This is definitely my prefered route. One option would be:
`opts &= ~ O_NONBLOCK; if (!block) opts |= O_NONBLOCK;` - but that's probably not better. Keeping code readable is much better than making it complex. This doesn't even look like a "hot-path" in the code, so I wouldn't worry about performance [not that I think it actually makes any difference]

Answer (score 1):

In the first version you can also use compound-assignment versions of the operators

```
if (block)
    opts &= ~O_NONBLOCK;
else
    opts |= O_NONBLOCK;
```

:)

Although I'd generally prefer `?:` operator over `if` whenever possible and appropriate. Yet in this specific situation it is hard to say what looks more elegant.

Comment: usually, I also prefer the `?:` operators, but for some reason this solution seems more elegant and more readable, too.